# Sharepoint online - MoveFile - pnp.powershell Status Updates

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to do folder/files moves from one sharepoint site to another, and I can't seem to get the Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus to work in my powershell script

Right now the only way I can monitor a file/folder move is to monitor the source's recycling bin for changes.  I'd like to be able to get progress either on demand, or consistently in an open powershell.  Ideally I'd like to see a percentage sign, and even a verbose option.

Here's what I have put together:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://<site>.sharepoint.com/
$SourceFolderURL= "sites/<site name>/<document library name>/<Folder or file location>"
$TargetFolderURL = "sites/<site name>/<document library name>"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -interactive

#Sharepoint Copy/Move operation feedback
$Test = "Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl $SourceFolderURL -TargetUrl $TargetFolderURL -Overwrite -noWait"
$jobStatus = "Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus -Job $Test"

if($jobStatus.JobState -eq 0)
{
  Write-Host "Job finished"
}
```

referencing:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/receive-pnpcopymovejobstatus?view=sharepoint-ps

I haven't been successful in running this. When I fill in the site names, library names, and actual site, I get a result that looks like it completes, but with no feedback, nor do the files move.  So essentially nothing happens.

What does work for the file/folder move is the following:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://<site>.sharepoint.com/"
$SourceFolderURL= "sites/<site name>/<document library>/<folder name>"
$TargetFolderURL = "sites/<site name>/<document library>"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -interactive
 
#sharepoint online powershell move folder
Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl $SourceFolderURL -TargetUrl $TargetFolderURL -overwrite 


#Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/06/how-to-move-folder-in-sharepoint-online.html#ixzz7Bkp822M1
```

Any help on correcting this script, or other methods on seeing the progress of Copy or Move operations on SharePoint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The source url should be like `"<document library>/<file name>"`
Please try following script

```
$SiteURL = "https://<site>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitesname>
$SourceFolderURL= "<document library name>/<file name>"
$TargetFolderURL = "<document library name>/<target file name>"

$job = Move-PnPFile -SiteRelativeUrl $SourceFolderURL -TargetUrl $TargetFolderURL -Overwrite
$jobStatus = Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus -Job $result
if($jobStatus.JobState == 0)
{
  Write-Host "Job finished"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried changing the site URL and I received an error.  When I use the original script I posted, it doesn't error, except at the Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus point.

I used the script you posted and got this error (but the files did move).

Comment: ```
Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Job' because it is null.
At C:\Users\Eric\Downloads\Powershell Script\INCOMPLETE Record Progress - Move FolderOrFiles - PnPPowershell.ps1:24 char:48
+ $jobStatus = Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus -Job $result
+                                                ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.ReceiveCopyMoveJobStatus
```

Comment: Here's what worked for file transfer, but not status:

`code
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://<sitre>.sharepoint.com"
$SourceFolderURL= "/sites/sharedfiles/shared Documents/TEST2"
$TargetFolderURL = "/sites/Customers/shared Documents"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -interactive

#Status
$job = Move-PnPFile -SiteRelativeUrl $SourceFolderURL -TargetUrl $TargetFolderURL -Overwrite
$jobStatus = Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus -Job $result
if($jobStatus.JobState -eq 0)
{
  Write-Host "Job finished"
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Your non-working script contains:

```
$Test = "Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl $SourceFolderURL -TargetUrl $TargetFolderURL -Overwrite -noWait"
$jobStatus = "Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus -Job $Test"
```

Both of these variable values are strings. They don't do anything except exist, and do not cause any commands to run. `$jobStatus.JobState` will always be null and never zero, because JobState is not a property of a string, so the if condition is never met.

If you want to run the commands, don't write them as strings inside double quotes, but just as they are in the documentation you referred to. You can actually run them, and capture their output, with e.g.

```
$jobStatus = Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus -Job $Test
```

You can also just copy and paste the example and update the parameter values (though it seems to have the wrong variable name on the second line, which you've already fixed). You may have further errors once the commands are running, which should provide further diagnostic information. Make sure that you are doing all of connecting, requesting the move, and retrieving the status information in the same script.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your feedback!  I'm just now getting time to work on this again this week.  I'll try this and report back.

Comment: = : The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.

The files Move to their locations, but no status message.
```
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -interactive

#Status
$job = Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl $SourceFolderURL -TargetUrl $TargetFolderURL -NoWait -Overwrite
$jobStatus = Receive-PnPCopyMoveJobStatus -Job $job
if($jobStatus.JobState -eq 0)
{
  Write-Host "Job finished"
}
```

Comment: That is the error you would get if you started the line with `=` and nothing on the left-hand side, or something like `$x == 1` (which is an assignment of the return value of `= 1`).

Comment: OK, I guess I'm not fully understanding what I'm missing here.

Comment: Yes, I don't see an obvious place for that to come out from the script you wrote, or the single-line version in the comment. If you have an unusual line break inside an assignment that could do it, or perhaps if there's some other surrounding script that really triggers the error. I'd suggest adding some debugging outputs to see where it starts to go wrong. It will probably be near an `=` sign with something atypical on its left.